# Cannot populate new lists during Realm migration? ( Objects are created but lists remains empty? )

Tags: list, react-native, migration, realm

#### Problem:

After modifying schema to add new list to an old object, I can NOT populate the new list during Realm migration?

- When new list is a list of objects, the new objects that are pushed **get created as expected.**
- However, **the resulting new list is always empty** when viewed in Realm Browser?

### Goals

To create a new list of objects and populate them during the Realm migration.

### Expected Results

I expect the new objects to be created and contained in the new object list.

### Actual Results

The object to push get created but the list remains empty?

I tried both object lists  and arrays of types.  Both array of strings and object lists remain empty.

### Steps to Reproduce

- 1) Add a new list to existing object.

  - Type does not seem to matter.
  - If type is an object, the object will be created, but never added to the list.
- 2) Updated schema version to force migration
- 3) During migration push new items onto the new string list and object list
- 4) I can console.log the list length and see it growing, but it does not get committed to the database?

#### Realm Schema:

```
PointContainer.schema = {
  name: 'PointContainer',
  schemaVersion,
  properties: {
    index: { type: 'int', default: -1 },
  },
};

class MyObject {
}
MyObject.schema = {
  name: 'MyObject',
  schemaVersion,
  properties: {
    uuidParent: { type: 'string' },

    // These are the two new lists added to schema
    // Goal: To populate lists during Realm migration
    newStringList: 'string[]',
    newPointContainerList: 'PointContainer[]',
  },
};
```

#### Realm Migration:

`export default new Realm({
  path: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'database.realm' : 'db/database.realm',
  schema: [
    MyObject,
    PointContainer,
  ],
  schemaVersion,
  migration(oldRealm, newRealm) {`

```
if (oldRealm.schemaVersion < SchemaVersionAddNewList) {
  try {
    const myObjectListOld = oldRealm.objects('MyObject');
    const myObjectListNew = newRealm.objects('MyObject');
    for (let i = 0; i < myObjectListOld.length; i += 1) {
      const myObjectOld = myObjectListOld[i];
      const myObjectNew = myObjectListNew[i];

      // This result is an empty myObjectNew.newStringList
      myObjectNew.newStringList.push('one');
      myObjectNew.newStringList.push('two');
      myObjectNew.newStringList.push('three');

      // New PointContainer objects will be created
      // This result is an empty myObjectNew.newPointContainerList
      myObjectNew.newPointContainerList.push({ index: 1});
      myObjectNew.newPointContainerList.push({ index: 2});
      myObjectNew.newPointContainerList.push({ index: 3});
    } //
  } catch (error) {
   // No errors are displayed or caught?
    console.log('dbg: *** Error migration:\n', error);
  }
}
```

},
});

### Version of Realm and Tooling

- "realm": "^2.15.3",
- "react": "16.3.1",
- "react-native": "0.55.4",
- iOS
- Which debugger for React Native: None

I am not 100% certain my migration code is correct.

I created issue here on Realm JS.
* https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1999

Thanks in advance,

-Ed